# Getting my swal fire error to display in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using vue and laravel and I'm also using sweet alert 2 for my error messages and I'm trying to get my error message to display if my product's status is not approved or it's empty, but it isn't showing up and I'm not getting anything in my console, but in my network tab the error is showing up.

Here is my code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center my-5">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="product.name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="description">Description</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" v-model="product.description">{{ product.description }}</textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" @click="updateProduct()">Update Product</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['product'],
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateProduct(){
            axios.put('/api/admin/products/'+this.product.id, {
                'name': this.product.name,
                'description': this.product.description
            }).then(response => {
                Swal.fire(
                    'Changes Saved',
                    'The product details have been updated',
                    'success'
                )
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                Swal.fire(
                    'Oops!',
                    err.message,
                    'error'
                )
            })
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        
    }
}
</script>
```

My function

```
public function updateProduct(Product $product)
{
    $outstanding = Product::where('status', 'pending')
        ->first();

    if(!empty($outstanding->status) && $outstanding->status != 'Approved')
    {
        return [
            'error' => "This product is not approved"
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an error status code to it using `response()` function. Default status code is 200 which means successful in axios. You need to tell axios that it is an error and catch it. So, providing an error status code will do this for you. [more info](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#response-objects)

```
if(!empty($outstanding->status) && $outstanding->status != 'Approved')
    {
        return response([
            'error' => "This product is not approved"
        ], 400);
    }
```

Additionally, you have a typo in your axios code. Change `err` to `error`

```
.catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
   Swal.fire(
      'Oops!',
      error.response.data.error,
      'error'
   )
})
```

Comment: That sort of works but I get this error message `Request failed with status code 400` instead of the one I want

Comment: Where did you get this error? at your console?

Comment: The `Request failed with status code 400` shows up in my swal fire pop up. The error message that I want the `"This product is not approved"` shows up in my network tab

Comment: I don't get any errors and in my console I have `undefined`

Comment: Ok. omit that trailing `error` and tell me what do you get when you do `console.log(error.responseJSON)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226252/discussion-between-babak-ashrafi-and-aurilie).